# не работает код игры "угадай число" для телеграма на python

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, я начинающий программист и я решил сделать игру "угадай число" для телеграма, но после команды /start бот только отправляет нужное сообщение и дальше ничего не происходит.
заранее спасибо за помощь

```
from aiogram import *

import random

bot = Bot(token'(скрыт)')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)



@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def help(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Я бот для игры в "угадай число" в телеграме. Для начала игры /start')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    r = random.randint(1, 50)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я загадал число от 1 до 50. Теперь попробуйте отгадать его. Никаких подсказок!' + str(r))
    if message.text == r:
        await message.reply('Поздравляю, ты угадал!')
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

пробовал добавить int() к 'message.text' и 'r' в 'if message.text == r:', но тогда выдает ошибку "invalid literal for int() with base 10"

Comment: https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать «машину состояний» для получения ответа пользователя, записи его в переменную и сравнения с загаданным числом. Так работает, проверил.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.utils import executor
import random

bot = Bot(token='TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN_HERE')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    random_number = State()
    number = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def help(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Hi! I am the Telegram bot. I can play Guess the number game. /start to start the game.')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await Form.random_number.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100. Try to guess it. (/cancel to stop the game)')

@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='stop', ignore_case=True), state='*')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await message.reply('Ok. The game was interrupted. /start to play again.')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.random_number)
async def random_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
       data['random_number'] = random.randint(1, 100)
    await Form.next()
    if int(message.text) == data['random_number']:
        await message.reply('Congratulations! You guessed!')
        await state.finish()
    elif int(message.text) > data['random_number']:
        await message.reply('Nope. The hidden number is less...')
    elif int(message.text) < data['random_number']:
        await message.reply('Nope. The hidden number is greater...')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.number)
async def answer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number'] = int(message.text)
    if data['number'] == data['random_number']:
        await message.reply('Congratulations! You guessed!')
        await state.finish()
    elif data['number'] > data['random_number']:
        await message.reply('Nope. The hidden number is less...')
        return answer
    elif data['number'] < data['random_number']:
        await message.reply('Nope. The hidden number is greater...')
        return answer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: а разве тогда бот не будет отвечать "угадал" или нет при любом тексте который совпадает с random.randint() независимо от того, выполнена команда /start или нет?

Comment: @RaYYeR _ 220, да, конечно будет. Сорри. Исправил ответ, добавив код, который решает эту проблему. Недавно писал бота, который использует [машину состояний](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html).

Comment: line 51, in <module>
    @dp.message_handler(state=Form.number)
NameError: name 'Form' is not defined

Comment: Класс определен? ```class Form(StatesGroup):
    number = State()```

Comment: разобрался, спасибо. Бот работает хорошо, но срабатывает только при ответе на его сообщение, а не на обычное сообщение. А так же бот срабатывает только на одно сообщение, то есть на правильный или не правильный ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать кол-во попыток неограниченным?

Comment: Исправил ответ. Добавил код, благодаря которому количество попыток не ограничивается. При этом, наверное, следует добавить возможность выхода из игры самостоятельно, если играть надоело. Добавил в ответ возможность отмены по команде /cancel или 'отмена' (со стр. 27 + import стр. 4).

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Исправил ответ. Я только начинаю изучать Python, поэтому не всегда могу предугадать последствия собственных действий. Извините. Дело в следующем: на сколько мне удалось разобраться, если использовать код из ответа с объявлением глобальной переменной ```global r``` и ```r = random.randint(1, 50)```, то решение отлично работает, если в игру одновременно играет не более одного человека. Если в это время игру начнет еще один человек, то ```random.randint``` отработает вновь, и значение переменной будет переопределено *(для первого участника загаданное число изменится прямо во время игры)*.

Comment: Чтобы избежать этого, я в конечный автомат добавил состояние загаданного числа и определял его в отдельной функции. Также я добавил в программу направляющие ответы бота: Нет, загаданное число больше *(или меньше)* — так играть интересней. Единственное — я не сумел придумать/нагуглить, как определить состояние загаданного числа не по событию *(сообщению пользователя)*, а как-то статически, поэтому у меня присутствует повторение в коде. Может, здесь кто-нибудь подскажет…